# How can I write arrays to a file with one column of int values and another float

Tags: python, numpy

I've written code to plot the average of two spectra, but I also need to write the average to a text file. I use the following command to do so (x3 and y3 are arrays containing the average x and y values):

```
np.savetxt('averaged_spectra.txt', np.transpose([x3,y3]))
```

This works well, however the values in the array x3 are actually four and five-digit integers, and the 18 digit float output I'm getting looks bad and is somewhat incongruous with the spectra files I began with. How can I write the elements of the x3 array as integer values while keeping the elements of y3 as float?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick way is to add the argument `fmt="%g"` to the [`savetxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) call:

```
np.savetxt('averaged_spectra.txt', np.transpose([x3,y3]), fmt="%g")
```

That tells `savetxt` to use `"%g"` as the format for each number.  It will print an integer-valued floating point number as an integer.

You can also use a format string containing two field specifications.  This gives you control of the format of each column.  For example,

```
np.savetxt('averaged_spectra.txt', np.transpose([x3,y3]), fmt="%6d  %26.18e")
```